# Implementing Linked List reversal using Stack

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, stack

I am trying to reverse a Linked List using Stack.

```
Node Reverse(Node head) {
    Stack<Node> x = new Stack<Node>();
    Node curr = new Node();
    curr= head;

    while (curr!=null){
        x.push(curr);
        curr=curr.next;

    }
    int i=0;
    while(!x.isEmpty()){
        if (i=0){
            head=x.pop();
            i++;
        }
        else{
            Node temp = new Node();
            temp = x.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my code. I am stuck in the while loop. Could you please help.?

Answer (score 1):

Your code below will run in a while loop infinitely.

```
if (i=0){
            head=x.pop();
            i++;
        }
```

You should change `i=0` to `i==0`

```
if (i==0){
                head=x.pop();
                i++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Node Reverse(Node head) {
    Stack<Node> x = new Stack<Node>();
    Node curr = new Node();
    curr= head;

    while (curr!=null){
        x.push(curr);
        curr=curr.next;

    }




            Node temp = new Node();
            temp=x.pop();
            head=temp;
            x.pop();
            while(!x.isEmpty()){
            temp = x.pop();
                if (x.peek()!=null){
            temp.next=x.peek();
            }
                else{
                    temp.next=null;
                }
            x.pop();
            temp=temp.next;    

            }

    return head;
}
```

I have taken lead till here. but still unable to deal with empty stack exception.

This is not a final solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's at least three problems with the code:

- as mentioned, `i=0` should be `i==0` in condition of the `if` statement;
- when you pop a non-head node off the stack, you're not doing any linking; you should probably say something like `prev.next = curr` where `curr` and `prev` are defined in an obvious way;
- the function is defined as returning a (reference to) `Node`; the code you gave doesn't return anything.

Also, I would suggest using the following iterative approach that's simpler and more efficient.

```
/* ... */
typedef struct node_t_ node_t;

struct node_t_ {
    node_t *next;
    int v;
};
/* ... */
node_t *reverse(node_t *head) {
    node_t *curr, *prev, *temp;

    prev = NULL;
    curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL) {
        temp = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = temp;
    }

    return prev;
}
```

I wrote the code in C; you should have no problems converting it to Java.

Answer (score 0):

At the core of programming is abstraction. You can make your code substantially simpler (and, hence, easier) by abstracting the linked list behind an interface. Once you’ve done it, the reversal via a stack is as simple as this:

```
void Reverse(LinkedList<T> list) {
    Stack<T> stack = new Stack<T>();

    while (! list.IsEmpty())
        stack.Push(list.RemoveFront());

    while (! stack.IsEmpty())
        list.AppendBack(stack.Pop());
}
```

That is, think of your list as a unit with its own interface, rather than passing around nodes in client code. Nodes are only touched *inside* the `LinkedList` class.